# Solve Speed Difference in ktrain Predictor vs. Learner prediction?

Tags: python, language-model, ktrain

I am using ktrain huggingface library to build a language model. When implementing it for production, I noticed, there is a huge difference in speed for a "learner prediction" vs. a "predictor prediction".
How come and is there any way to speed up the predictor prediction?

```
%timeit test = learner.predict(val) # takes 10s
%timeit test = predictor.predict(x_val,return_proba = True) # takes 25s
```

Answer (score 0):

The second call preprocesses the data (e.g., tokenization), whereas the first call is making a prediction on data that is already preprocessed.  So, the time difference is likely due to the time it is taking to preprocess the raw data:

```
%%time
tst = predictor.preproc.preprocess_test(x_test)
# Wall time: 5.65 s

%%time 
preds = learner.predict(val)
# Wall time: 10.5 s

%%time
preds = predictor.predict(x_test)
# Wall time: 16.1 s
```

When supplying a list of texts to `predict`, you can also use a larger `batch_size` that may also help increase speed (default is 32):

```py
predictor.batch_size = 128
preds = predictor.predict(x_test)
```

Finally, if you're looking to make faster predictions in a deployment scenario, you can look at the **ktrain** FAQ, where it shows [how to make quantized predictions](https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-make-quantized-predictions-with-transformers-models) and [predictions with ONNX](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/develop/examples/text/ktrain-ONNX-TFLite-examples.ipynb).